# htaccess redirect problems, Wordpress and static html site not redirecting properly

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having problems with a customer's website. I've created a new Wordpress site for him and now I'm having problems with htaccess redirecting.

Before I installed Wordpress on the server, there was two static basic HTML-sites. One in the public_html root using the main domain and a completely different subsite in a subfolder with a htaccess rewrite rule directing the subdomain into that folder.

Now there is Wordpress messing up the redirects. Wordpress of course made modifications to the original htaccess-file. In addition to that, the customer also had to change servers within the hosting provider to get newer php version so I had to write the htaccess file from scratch.

Here is the current htaccess-file :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /www/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?subdomainurl.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomainfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomainfolder/$1 [L]
```

Wordpress in installed in a folder named www and the url is being rewritten, it works beautifully. But I'm having problems with the subdomain. In the code above I've replaced the subdomain url with subdomainurl.com, the site lies in public_html/subdomainfolder/.

Now, when I type www.subdomainurl.com, the redirect works, the site is shown. But www.subdomainurl.index.html typed doesn't. It has to be written www.subdomainurl.com/subdomainfolder/index.html, so I'm clearly not writing the redirect right, adding the subdomain folder as well. I've tried to mingle with that htaccess but can't get it right. Everytime I try to change something I get a 404 in the main domain's Wordpress site.

At the moment these work:
www.maindomain.com/subdomainfolder/index.html
www.subdomainurl.com/subdomainfolder/index.html

And this doesn't, which I'm trying to do:
www.subdomainurl.com/index.html

I'm not a redirect expert, any help would be much appreciated.

*Edit/Addon :*

Here is the old code from the old server that redirected the subdomain to the subfolder and rewrote the url, it doesn't work anymore so I ditched it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?subdomainurl.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomainfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomainfolder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?subdomainurl.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdomainfolder/index.html [L]
```

Comment: So in short, I just need to remove the folder name from the final url in this htaccess-file.

From
www.subdomainurl.com/subdomainfolder/index.html
to
www.subdomainurl.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an entry in the htaccess file for just the subdomain and for the main domain.

Comment: What do you mean?

There are currently two domains pointing to the same web hosting space. The secondary one is mentioned in the .htaccess, the primary one isn't since they both are directed to the web space root as default by the provider and folder redirection has to be done by .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using this code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /www/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?subdomainurl.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdomainfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdomainfolder$1
```

This loads the whole secondary domain (subdomainurl.com) as www.subdomainurl.com/subdomainfolder and it works like that (www.subdomainurl.com/subdomainfolder/index.html, www.subdomainurl.com/subdomainfolder/work.html etc.), but it still isn't what the customer really wanted. I still need to eliminate the subdomainfolder-part from the url by htaccess, so far I haven't had success. I suppose I haven't got it right on the final row of the code.